# SQL Server Insert if not exist

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, insert

I know that SELECT + INSERT is a bad practice that can lead to race condition (learned from insert-update antipattern when some who try to implement a upsert behaviour).

But I have no idea how to avoid that when I would just insert data in a table without duplicate for a given column (or tuple of column):

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT TOP(1) 1 FROM [tbl_myTable] WHERE [MyNotKeyField] = 'myValue' )
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO [tbl_myTable] (...) VALUES (...)
END
```

Should I create an unique index and just try to insert the record anyway?
I am afraid that in this case the overhead of failed insert may be more costly.

PS: I am sending that command from a client application (C# application connected with SQL Server) so I suppose temporary table and use of MERGE is out of the question.

Comment: Why MERGE is out? I guess, you can send this command from your client

Comment: You can still use temporary tables and merge statements from a stored procedure and can trigger the procedure from the c# application.

Comment: You could add that unique and do the if statement at the same time. You are making sure "MyNotKeyField" is unique, then why not just add that constraint? It may cause some extra action, but it also takes longer to find that record indicated by WHERE clause if not using index

Comment: @BrianHolsen i am not against the index, i am afraid that select+insert (regardless the index) may cause deadlock (it happened to me when i had used select + insert/update antipattern). I have created such index so no problem about that, i have doubt about my actual query or relying entirely on the index

Comment: @JamshaidK. you are reight, but it become a bit too complex IMHO.
So for mantainability reasons i would solve it only with client code and without temporary table (that will also put pressure on temp db)

Comment: Maybe you could try using transaction, get the exclusive lock with select statement (never tried this way in app code). Or just throw it in a stored procedure.

Comment: @BrianHolsen yes i can, but i have suspicius that could be costly because for each exception (i expect many of the) i have the error handling extra cost. Geezer solution sound simpler and faster, or you know fallacies about that solution?

Comment: @BrianHolsen Why would "throw it in a stored procedure" help, there is still no inherent locking without a transaction

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Combine the `EXISTS` with `INSERT`

eg

```
INSERT INTO [tbl_myTable] (...) 
SELECT @val1, @val2 ...
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM [tbl_myTable] WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE)
    WHERE [MyNotKeyField] = 'myValue'
);
```

Aaron Bertrand has a [great post](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern) on anti UPSERT patterns